# Log stdout + stderr and stderr simultaneously in R

Tags: r, logging, stdout, stderr, error-messaging

I want to have all `stdout + stderr` in one log file and simultaneously just `stderr` in another. How can I achieve this in R? Messages must keep the chronological order of all messages in both logs, for example say I have this code:

```
options(warn = 1)
cat("1st stdout\n")
warning("2nd stderr")
cat("3rd stdout\n")
warning("4th stderr")
```

How to make it redirect to both logs in the desired way?

My thought that it could be simple if it was possible to merge and split the [R connections](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html), see the question here: [How to merge and split R connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60925391/684229)

I am not against special logging frameworks, but it is preferable to be able to log from functions like `cat`, `warning`, `message`, `stop` etc. without changing the code to different functions (since I also use different packages).